# How stable is stableId?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

The JavaDoc for `EntityProxy.stableId()` says:

```
"An id returned by a proxy newly created by RequestContext.create 
Object.equals(Object) those returned later by proxies to the persisted object."
```

Does that mean that the stable id will be valid for that object across different request contexts? across different request factory instances? I suppose I'm asking what is the scope of the stable id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EntityProxyId` object has a global scope and is suitable for long-term use as a `Map` key or member of a `Set`.  `EntityProxyId` objects can be used across different instances and types of a `RequestFactory` (assuming that the proxy type is reachable from the `RequestFactory` in question). The `RequestFactory.getHistoryToken()` and `getProxyId` methods can create a string representation of an `EntityProxyId` that is suitable for client-side persistence.

The one exception to the global scope of an `EntityProxyId` is the id of a newly-created `EntityProxy` that has not yet been persisted on the server.  An "ephemeral" id is only usable with the `RequestFactory` from which the newly-created proxy object is derived.  Once the proxy has been sent to the server and the server has provided a non-null id, the ephemeral id is upgraded to a persistent id and becomes indistinguishable from any other persistent id.  The object identity of the upgraded `EntityProxyId` does not change, so ephemeral ids can be added to `Map` or `Set` and be retrieved later.

Comment: Could an ephemeral id be created by one request context, and later be used by another request context that is associated with the same request factory?